# Chromebook unique identifier in enterprise setting

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-admin-sdk, google-chrome-os, google-admin-settings-api

I'm looking for a way in a chrome extension/app to retrieve a unique identifier for a device.
I've found this API:  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/enterprise_deviceAttributes
but I don't want to have to put everyone on the dev channel.

Does anyone know of any way I could uniquely identify a device in an enterprise setting?

Thanks!

Comment: Strange: the docs for that API list it as experimental yet in the API index it's listed as Stable since Chrome 46. Can you see if it's actually unavailable in Stable? (don't have a CrOS device to test myself)

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like it works in the stable version.  I guess the docs are just old.